# Definition of Singular Set

Tags: real-analysis

so i have the following set $C_{a}= \{(x,y)\in R^{2} | x^{4}+4x=y^{5}+5ay \}$, where $R$ is the set of real numbers.

$\bullet$ I am asked to find $a$ such that $C_{a}$ is singular. However I do not understand what they mean by singular.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that in this cases it means that the curve represented by the set has a singular point.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve